# Do you gain war weariness when your cities participate in combat?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

**The Wiki**

The [Wiki](https://civ6.gamepedia.com/g00/War_weariness?i10c.encReferrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8%3D&i10c.ua=1&i10c.dv=14) states that war weariness is increased when units participate in combat (either attacker or defender) and it states that taking a city, regardless of razing or keeping, doesn't affect war weariness.

**Question**

It does not, however, state whether a city participating in combat increases war weariness. The unit participating in the combat with the city would definitely increase the owner's war weariness but would the owner of the city gain war weariness?

**Notes**

Just to be clear, I mean when attacking a city directly and not having a unit attack from a city district tile. I assume this does not change with R&F, however if it does please let me know.

Comment: A city does not count as a unit in any other way, so I'm inclined to say that it doesn't (for the city owner). But I lack the proof.